# Stanford Lemmatizer in NLTK

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, stanford-nlp, lemmatization

I know how to setup stanford NERTagger and POSTagger in NLTK, but can anyone tell me how can I use stanford Lemmatizer in NLTK? I have tried to search but did not find any helpful solution

Comment: did you find an answer ?!